# Crossing out lines of printed values: Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given my current code below I am wondering how I could cross a line through any rows that have the b value as even. So, for example, it would print something like this: 3̶4̶ ̶2̶2̶  or something similar.

```
a=int(input("Input first value: "))
b=int(input("Input second value: "))
def get_product(a, b):
product = 0
while b:
    if b % 2:
        product += a
    a *= 2
    b //=2
  return product
Prod=(get_product(a, b))
print(a,b)
while b>1:
   b=b//2
   a=a*2
   print(a,b)
print("Product: ",Prod)
```

Comment: what have you done till now. share the code. Share the sample data

Comment: This question is tagged with "line" and "multiple-columns" but I'm not sure what the relevance is? Were you expecting this in an Excel file with strikethroughs or something?

Comment: Those were mistakes on my part for the tags and I will add some sample code once I get back home.

Comment: @TylerGubala Tags are now fixed. Sorry for the confusion I'm new to all of this.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I now have it updated with what I have done. As well as made it much clearer what I've been trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think this question is about "crossing out the line". That "crossing out" phrase was used only to illustrate the fact that you won't need the number when adding up the sum to find the final product.

Comment: @blhsing Honestly I think you're right. It seems a little unnecessary for the line if you ask me.

Comment: So far i still don't know how to do this or if it's even possible. However, thanks to everyone that put effort in to help me out. I'm new to coding and i deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the said logic with a `while` loop:

```
def get_product(a, b):
    product = 0
    while b:
        if b % 2:
            product += a
        a *= 2
        b //= 2
    return product
```

so that:

```
print(get_product(4, 6), 4 * 6)
print(get_product(13, 37), 13 * 37)
print(get_product(231, 67), 231 * 67)
```

would output:

```
24 24
481 481
15477 15477
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet but if I could I would. Thanks for the help, it really smoothed out the process to get the Product!

Comment: Is there any issue with this answer that made you un-accept it?

Comment: Well, I recently changed the question up a bit so it doesn't exactly match perfectly.